# How to build image name/path from two select/option id by Javascript

Tags: javascript, path, html-select

I'm trying to bulid an image path from two select fields. I have to use the "id"s because "value"s are used already. Unfortunatedly only the second select works. Does anyone have a hint? As you might see I'm not a coder. Could anyone be so kind and help to make the code more elegant/slim?
I use onchange to update the "result1" and "result2" allways when the user alters his selection.
Thanks in advance, Georg

Here is my code:

```js
<script>
  function showOptions1(s) {
  document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = "<img src='img/preview/" + s[s.selectedIndex].id;
}
</script>
<script>
  function showOptions2(s) {
  document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = s[s.selectedIndex].id + ".jpg'>";
}
</script>
```

```html
<select  onchange="showOptions1(this)" id="my_select1">
   <option value="werta" id="1">Text Item 1a</option>
   <option value="wertb" id="2">Text Item 1b</option>
</select>

<select  onchange="showOptions2(this)" id="my_select2">
   <option value="wertc" id="3">Text Item 1c</option>
   <option value="wertd" id="4">Text Item 1d</option>
</select>

<span id="result1"></span><span id="result2"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the onchange event because you want the user to select two things before building the path.  So, put another button on the screen called "save image" or something like that.  The onclick of this button gets the "value" of each select input and concats them together.  You can easily get a handle to the select inputs using jquery by name

```
var select1 = $("#my_select1");
```

Now your problem is that you don't want the value.  That would be easy.  Instead you want the select option and then you want to get the id.  You can do that as follows

```
var my1id = $("#my_select1 option:selected" ).id;
```

Comment: You should use `[0].id`

Comment: Yes, correct, thanks.  You have to get the original DOM object from the jquery one before using the dot.  So it would be var my1id = $("#my_select1 option:selected" )[0].id;

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your support. Cheers Georg

Finaly I use this code (and stick to onchange because I dont want another button because there are allready three of them):

```
<script>

    var selection01, selection02;

    showOptions1 = function(s) {

        selection01 = "<img src='img/preview/" + s[ s.selectedIndex ].id;

        getResult();


    };

    showOptions2 = function(s) {

        selection02 = s[ s.selectedIndex ].id + ".jpg' width='200px;'>";

        getResult();

    };

    function getResult() {

        var total = selection01 + selection02;

        console.log( total );

        document.getElementById("Image").innerHTML = total;

    };

</script>

<select id="select1" onchange="showOptions1(this)">
    <option value="" id="01" selected>...</option>
    <option value="werta" id="10">Text Item 1a</option>
    <option value="wertb" id="20">Text Item 1b</option>
</select>

<select id="select2" onchange="showOptions2(this)">
    <option value="" id="02" selected>...</option>
    <option value="wertc" id="30">Text Item 1c</option>
    <option value="wertd" id="40">Text Item 1d</option>
</select>

<hr><span id="Image"></span>
```